# Slide divs in and out using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a large 3D carousel filling up most of the page. I want it to slide down off the page on a click event while another div slides up to take the same position.

Essentially, there will be three carousels (each different in amount of slides and with unique content), and they'll each have their own corresponding button to slide the current div down off screen and reveal the clicked div.

This is what I'm working with so far: http://werdnaworks.com/DEMO/

Comment: This is about as close of an explanation I can find. Although, I can't get it to work for the life of me. http://tinyurl.com/mbas49g

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set each `<div>`'s position to `absolute` then animate the `top` property with jQuery:

```
animate({top: 'value'}, 'slow'};
```

sample html markup:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Carousel 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Carousel 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Carousel 3</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="carousel-1">Carousel 1</div>
<div id="carousel-2">Carousel 2</div>
<div id="carousel-3">Carousel 3</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('li').click(function(){
    var ind = $(this).index();

    $('div').each(function(index, element){
        if(index == ind){
            $(this).animate({top: 0},'slow');
        }else{
            $(this).animate({top: '100%'},'slow');
        }
    });
})
```

And here is the sample [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mark_s/CYPQK/).